# SonarQube Scanner - Disable Duplication Calculation in Specific File

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a directory that contains both generated and non-generated files. Neither of the generated or non-generated files have a filename identifier (such as *Generated.java). I need sonar to calculate duplication in the non-generated files but not in the generated files. For practical business reasons, I cannot restructure or rename these files.

- I have looked through [Narrowing the Focus](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreDuplications) multiple times and cannot find a way to do what I am looking for.
- I have also tried using [Ignore Issues](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues) but this does not ignore duplication, only sonar "Issues".
- Ideally, I would like to provide my code generator with a way to let sonar know that the file should be ignored **for duplications only**. That is, the file should still be included in the analysis for any issues but will not add to the code duplication total. (This would provide a maintainable solution for me rather than having to manually exclude all non-generated files in the present and future)

Is there a solution that I am overlooking? There doesn't seem to be any built-in functionality in Sonar for this. If not, is there a work-around?

Please let me know if there is any more needed information.

Thank you.

Comment: The `Narrowing the focus` document has a short `Ignoring duplications` section. Why does that not work for you?

Comment: It does work for ignoring a single file or path. It doesn't work for me because I cannot restructure my files and they do not have any similar naming conventions. If I were to use this, I would need to currently manually enter 50+ file names and if, in the future, more files are added, I will need to go back into the project settings and add those new files to this list. If I instead have a way to do it inside the java file, all of this can be done automatically and is much more maintainable.

Comment: I have been unable to find other options. Group the files you want to exclude from the duplications check in one package and exclude that, or manually enter all file names separately.

Comment: Yep, the Sonar documentation seems to be lacking in quite a few areas though, so I'm sure there is a workaround I just haven't found it yet. My initial thought was to build a generator that would put all of it in the sonar-project.properties but it looks like it has to be done on the server properties (only through the Server UI). That's really unfortunate.

Answer (score 2):

You can always create a sonar configuration file in your project's root directory'sonar-project.properties' and add the file to your duplications exclusion list like:

```
sonar.cpd.exclusions=src/main/java/com/%FileToBeExcluded%.java
```

For more info: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/

Answer (score -2):

This is at least possible with sonarqube version 7.5 (the only version I have tested). Following the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreDuplications) it (now) says

> Ignore Code Coverage
>
> You can prevent some files from being taken into account for code coverage by unit tests.
> To do so, go to Administration > General Settings > Analysis Scope > Code Coverage and set the Coverage Exclusions property.

For me, adding an entry with `src/debug.hpp` made it go away from the duplication list (it contains multiple generated 1 to N arguments template functions to support `debug("string")`, `debug("string", var)` etc).